# How enable next checkbox if top checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<lable>Checkbox 1</lable>
<input type="checkbox" class="fields" checked/>
<br>
<lable>Checkbox 2</lable>
<input type="checkbox" class="fields" checked/>
<br>
<lable>Checkbox 3</lable>
<input type="checkbox" class="fields" checked />
<br>
<lable>Checkbox 4</lable>
<input type="checkbox" class="fields" checked/>
<br>
<lable>Checkbox 5</lable>
<input type="checkbox" class="fields" checked/>


$('[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
  var $this = this;
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    return;
  var uncheck = false;
  $('[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
      if (this === $this){
        uncheck = true;
      }
    
      if (uncheck){
        this.checked = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Once the any top checkbox is unchecked all below check boxes will unchecked automatically, but i want when any top check is checked next checkbox only should be enabled, when user check that box another checkbox should enable.

Comment: No unlimited checkbox , basically these check boxes will be fetch from database based on user input.
basically i want if any check box is unchecked from middle example 2nd checkbox i want all below check boxes to be disabled but 3rd checkbox should be enable for checking , if 3rd checkbox checked only next checkbox should be enabled .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your last comment, you can add unlimited checkbox, if any checkbox unchecked from middle then next all checkbox will be disabled..

```js
$('.fields').on('click', function() {

    let nextChk = $(this).nextAll('.fields');
    
    // checked
    if( this.checked ){
        // find the next checkbox and disabled it 
        if( nextChk.first().length )
           nextChk.first().attr('disabled', false);
    }
    // unchecked
    else{
        // find all checkboxes, disable and check it
        nextChk.each(function(){
           $(this).attr('disabled', true);
           $(this).prop('checked', false);
        });
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Checkbox 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="fields" checked/>
<br>
<label>Checkbox 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="fields" checked/>
<br>
<label>Checkbox 3</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="fields" checked/>
<br>
<label>Checkbox 4</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="fields" checked/>
<br>
<label>Checkbox 5</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="fields" checked/>
```

Comment: Clever use of `nextAll()` and `:first`! You might want to correct the faulty `<label>` elements in the HTML markup too.

Comment: Thanks @cars10m, have corrected `<label>` and improved with declaring one variable also..

Comment: Thanks it worked but can we make all checkbox pre checked and when user uncheck any checkbox below checkboxes should be unchecked and disabled.
How can we enable first checkbox and keeping all below checkbox disabled.

Comment: You have specified 2 things, What you want from two things? 1) can we make all checkbox pre checked and when user uncheck any checkbox below checkboxes should be unchecked and disabled. 2) How can we enable first checkbox and keeping all below checkbox disabled.

Comment: 1) can we make all checkbox pre checked and when user uncheck any checkbox below checkboxes should be unchecked and disabled.

this will definately helps

[.] cb1
[.] cb2
[.] cb3
[.] cb4
[.] cb5

on un check cb3

[.] cb1
[.] cb2
[] cb3 (unchecked)
[] cb4  (unchecked & disabled)
[} cb5  (unchecked & disabled)

Answer (score 1):

This does at least part of the job (enabling the next checkbox):

```js
var cbs=$('[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
 let nxt=cbs.get(cbs.index(this)+1)
 if (nxt) nxt.disabled=false;
  
}).slice(1).prop('disabled',true).end();
```

```css
input:checkbox {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<label>Checkbox 1
<input type="checkbox" class="fields"/></label>
<br>
<label>Checkbox 2
<input type="checkbox" class="fields"/></label>
<br>
<label>Checkbox 3
<input type="checkbox" class="fields"/></label>
<br>
<label>Checkbox 4
<input type="checkbox" class="fields"/></label>
<br>
<label>Checkbox 5
<input type="checkbox" class="fields"/></label>
</form>
```

Comment: But when user uncheck any top checkbox it should disable all below checkboxes .